# How can I be closed to the outside network but open to the inside network in Linux?

Tags: networking

How can I be closed to the outside network but open to the inside network in Linux? There was a route command for this. I can't find it. My foreign language is not good... My local network should be active but the external internet should be turned off.

Comment: You could delete the default route, but it would be better to set up firewall rules.

Comment: Can you define more completely what you mean by "closed"?  Do you want other sources on the inside network to reach your computer when they initiate connections?  Do you want your computer to be able to reach other destinations on the inside network when your computer initiates connections?  Do you want connections to the outside Internet to succeed when your computer initiates the connections?

Answer (score 1):

To close off external network access while keeping the local network active in Linux, you can use the `iptables` command to block all outgoing traffic except for the local network. Here’s a concise way to do it:

Allow all traffic on your local network (replace **192.168.1.0/24** with your local network range):

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Block all other outgoing traffic:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

These commands allow devices on your local network to communicate with each other while blocking access to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ip route delete default
```

Network Manager may interfere with that.